# Cannot Import 'ParametricRegion' from 'sympy.vector'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I was trying the code for [Stoke's Theorem](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/vector_integration.html#verifying-stoke-s-theorem) in Sympy Docs and it's throwing the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParametricRegion' from 'sympy.vector' (/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/vector/__init__.py)
```

I tried Googling and there is no docs about ParametricRegion being depreciated or moved (far as I searched). Every document I could find uses it freely.

Further, I noticed that it throws the same error for ImplicitRegion as well.

I tried in both JupyterLab and Sympy Live Shell.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it myself: leaving the answer here, hoping that someone will find it useful in future:

Going by the Sympy Docs in GitHub, ParametricRegion was introduced in [Sympy 1.7](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/releases/download/sympy-1.7/sympy-docs-pdf-1.7.pdf). ([Sympy Docs 1.6](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/releases/download/sympy-1.6/sympy-docs-pdf-1.6.pdf))

JupyterLab (on Binder) runs Sympy 1.4 and SympyLive runs on version 1.5.1, hence, both are throwing the error.